# Firebase storage endpoint with PDF file not secure

Tags: firebase, networking, google-cloud-platform, cross-domain, firebase-storage

I am serving a PDF via Firebase storage. It works for most users but now one user is sitting on a workplace network that seems to have stonger rules for file downloading and get this message: Security risk blocked for your protection, see image:

[image]

The Firebase storage rules look like this:

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

Any ideas on if there is some ways to make this file show as more secure and work for the user in this case?

**update:**
If I open link in gmail app it also showed warning, and looks like also in Edge.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Firebase or security rules.  The user's firewall is blocking access.

Answer (score 1):

Tools like zscalar can incorrectly flag the firebase storage googleapi URL as phishing.

Comment: Interesting, sounds quite crazy. I got now an warning also when trying to open the link via my gmail mail app: Suspicious content this link leads to an untrusted site. Are you sure you want to proceed firebase. Hehe its also suspicious for Google. And looks like also for Edge.